# change Wishlist price phtml template

Tags: magento-1.9, wishlist

using the template hints feature I noticed that the template used to render the price of each product in the wishlist is

```
"template/catalog/product/price.phtml".
```

I would like to change this path to use a custom phtml template, only for the wishlist page, but I can't find the place where it can be changed.

Anyone has suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the thing to do is edit the file wishlist.xml in the layout folder of the template and search for the tags that define the layout of the column "price" of the wishlist items. this is the edit:

```
<block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_column_cart" name="customer.wishlist.item.price" template="wishlist/item/column/price.phtml">
                        <action method="setTitle" translate="title">
                            <title>Price</title>
                        </action>
                        <!-- change the price block for items in wishlist -->
                        <action method="addPriceBlockType">
                            <type>simple</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>path/to/custom/price.phtml</template>
                        </action>
                        <action method="addPriceBlockType">
                            <type>grouped</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>path/to/custom/price.phtml</template>
                        </action>
                        <action method="addPriceBlockType">
                            <type>configurable</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>path/to/custom/price.phtml</template>
                        </action>
                        <action method="addPriceBlockType">
                            <type>virtual</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>path/to/custom/price.phtml</template>
                        </action>
                        <action method="addPriceBlockType">
                            <type>bundled</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>path/to/custom/price.phtml</template>
                        </action>
                        <block type="wishlist/customer_wishlist_item_options" name="customer.wishlist.item.options" />
</block>
```